# Update multiple fields of a document in MongoDB using Mongoose, Node Js and Express

Tags: node.js, json, ajax, mongodb, express

I understand this question has been asked and answered many times before, however the issue that I am facing is not being solved after various attempts.

I have collection called `properties` which has a field called rentRange and is structured as shown below

```
rentRange: {
        min: {type: Number},
        max: {type: Number}
    }
```

Now there are two options for the user. Either he can set the price of rent to be a singular amount or he can keep it as a range.

For example if rent is 5000 units then

```
rentRange: {
            min: 5000,
            max: 5000
        }
```

And if it is set to a range then

```
 rentRange: {
                min: 5000,
                max: 6000
            }
```

One can change and update the number using an AJAX call as shown below

```
$.ajax({
            type:'PUT',
            url: '/updatePrice',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                rentRange:{
                    _id: id,
                    min: from,
                    max: to
                }
            }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            _csrf: "{{csrfToken}}",
            success: function(data){

            }
        });
```

And this request is taken at this route

**index.js**

```
router.put('/updatePrice', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next){
    let id = req.body.rentRange._id;
    let pmin = Number(req.body.rentRange.min);
    let pmax = Number(req.body.rentRange.max);

    Property.update({_id: req.body.rentRange._id}, {$set : {rentRange:{min: pmin, max: pmax}}})
        .then((data)=> {
            console.log(data);
            return res.json({message: data});
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            return next({message: `Error updating User`});
        });
});
```

There is no issue when I send `rentRange` to have no range and the min and max values are equal. However, the issue arises when `pmin` and `pmax` have different values. The status shows `200` however there is no update and simply the previous values remain and the following is shown in the console log

```
{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

After much surfing I came across various ways to change the querying part and used the following methods :-

**Method 1**

```
 Property.findById(id, function(err, prop){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       }else{
           console.log(prop);
           prop.rentRange.min = min;
           prop.rentRange.max = max;

           prop.save(function(err){
               if(err){
                   console.log(err);
               }
               else{
                   res.json(prop);
               }
           });
       }
    });
```

**Method 2**

```
Property.update({_id: req.body.rentRange._id}, {$set : {"rentRange.min": pmin, "rentRange.max": pmax}})
        .then((data)=> {
            console.log(data);
            return res.json({message: data});
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            return next({message: `Error updating User`});
        });
```

However, the same issue persists where the range values are not updated and single values are changed.

I cannot seem to identify the error. I'm assuming it's something very silly or small however I need some more clarity on the solution.

> PS: Sorry for the long post :p

Comment: Sure seems like you're providing the wrong _id value when it's not working. I think we'd need a [MCVE] to help further.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I just checked with console.log(id) and for the range values it is coming as "undefined". However, why is that so? @JohnnyHK

Comment: You'll need to debug that in your client; see what it's sending and why.

Comment: Solved the problem. ID being taken for the range values was wrong. Thank you so much for pointing it out :)